# How to make a button scroll inside a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

It's possible to put a button inside a scroll view and make it scroll together with the view?

I try to explain the issue.
I have a scrollView containing a textView showing some text. In the text there's a link and i have a button, put beside this link that, when pressed, open the link in safari. Now, the text is longer than the textView, so i had to put the Text view inside a Scroll View to make it scroll. I tried putting the button inside the scrollView as well, but when i scroll, only the text get scrolled and the button stays still where it is, when instead i want the button to scroll together with the text, to have it evere beside the link that is in the text.
Is is possible?

Comment: It's all an Interface Builder issue... there's no code, as far.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, you can't put controls inside a `UITextView`.

You could implement your desired behaviour by moving the button during the textView's [`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate)
 delegate method.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // Move button according to scroll position, using scrollView.contentOffset
}
```