# ios - How to make a button scroll with a textView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a bunch of text inside a textView, and a button inline with this text that opens a modal window when clicked. However, when I try to scroll, the button stays in place while the rest of the text moves. Does anyone know how to get it to move with the rest of the text?

I looked at this question ([How to make a button scroll inside a UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270377/how-to-make-a-button-scroll-inside-a-uiscrollview)) which seems similar, but the answer given wasn't particularly helpful.

I'm very new to development in swift, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: That question looks like it has the right answer to me. Can you give more details (maybe a screenshot) and what your view hierarchy looks like (code or show us an IB screenshot)

Comment: The problem isn't that I tried it and it failed; its that I don't understand it well enough to implement it. I'm being called on to do this in like my second week ever of working with Swift. All the answers I've seen are going over my head.

Answer (score 0):

Since TextViews inherits from ScrollViews, you are able to use scrolls view's delegate methods. Be sure to add UITextViewDelegate to your class and set your textfield delegate to self: **textField.delegate = self**

After doing that you can use functions from scrollview delegate. With 
**func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)** you can detect when your textview is being scrolled. Every time you scroll it you'll have to know how much it has scrolled. For that you can use the property **content​Offset** of scrollviews.

Once you've got that position change every time the text scroll, you'll have to update the button position, creating a new **frame** exactly like the old one with a new **y**.

I believe that will solve your problem! I hope it helps :)